# Coalesced access in opencl

Tags: optimization, opencl

I am studying opencl with the sample code histogram.cpp from the book OpenCl programming by example chapter 2.

In the opencl kernel

```css
for i ... 
       uint value = data[globalId * BIN_SIZE + i];
```

for this line, each thread access a consecutive memory space, the threads in a warp do not coalesced access the global memory. So I changed to the following,

```css
uint value = data[offset + i * groupSize + localId];
```

such that the threads in a warp coalesced access the global memory.

It is expected that the 2nd way takes shorter running time. However the result gets the opposite. I have tested the program on different NVIDIA GPU devices, I got the same results, the 1st way takes shorter time than the 2nd way.

Any one could give me some advices. Thanks in advance.

BTW, the code can be downloaded by https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/14707

Comment: is i equal to group id in the second example?

Comment: If your BIN_SIZE is 2 or 4 it is almost certain you will end up with a faster vector version in the final binary.